# Chart.js: How can I manually set Y-axis range?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am looking for a way to set Y-axis ticks manually. The reason to do that is that I am plotting % graph and some values are under 100 while others above 2000% or so. So I want to set first few values w.r.t 100 and on top in 1000s scale.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38386726/set-y-axis-scale-manually-in-a-bar-chart-using-angular-chart-js).
As the solution there suggest to try with yAxes type as 'logarithmic' and have basic tick configurations. With the mentioned axis type, you can provide Y-Axis  min and max value.

Comment: This should be a comment... Not an answer

Comment: True, unfortunately I could not comment directly as I am short of 4 reputations to do that. Hence provided a direction to the asker. However I am able to comment under a comment